# Octave appending in a 2D cell array

Tags: matlab, octave, cell-array

I'm trying to append an element at the end of a 2D cell array row. My code is:

```
b = cell(5, 0)
b(1) = {b(1, :), 2}   % Trying to append at the end of the first row
```

This gives me the error: `error: A(I) = X: X must have the same size as I`

I've also tried various other forms, such as:

```
b = cell(5, 0)
b(1, end+1) = 2   % Ok, inserts 2 at [1,1]
b(2, end+1) = 3   % No, inserts 3 at [2,2] instead of [2, 1]
```

Comment: why should `b(2, end+1) = 3` insert `3` at `[1 1]`?

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant `[2 1]`

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you are confused with cell array indexing.

If you want to append elements at the end of a row in a matrix (in your case, a cell array), you must still make sure that all rows are of the same size after the assignment, otherwise you'll trigger an error about mismatching dimensions.

Instead of `b(1) = {b(1, :), 2}`, the following should work:

```
b(1, end + 1) = 2
```

Alternatively, if you want to append an entire column array of cells to `b`, use horizontal concatenation, for example:

```
b = [b, {2; 3; 4; 5; 6}];
```

This should append a single cell at the end of each row of `b`.

Comment: Actually, i know that there will be 5 rows. But I don't know in advance how many columns each of the rows will contain. How to initialize the cell array in this case?

Comment: @RafiKamal It was unclear from your question, but now I understand. You've initialized your cell array fine, you just need to concatenate horizontally then. I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the element gets inserted at `[2, 2]` and not `[1, 1]` is that by the time you try to insert the second element, the value denoted by `end` has increased from `0` to `1`.

The following should do what you need:

```
>> b = cell(5, 0)

b = 

Empty cell array: 5-by-0

>> b(1,1) = {2}

b = 

    [2]
    []
    []
    []
    []

>> b(2,1) = {3}

b = 

    [2]
    [3]
    []
    []
    []

>>
```